# count of occurances in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my dataset looks likes this after executing groupby. How can I sum the common systems in column 3

[image]

Comment: groupby and agg seems to be appropriate in your case. `df.groupby('col1').agg({'col3':count})`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using pandas `.value_counts()` method:

```
df['col3'].value_counts()
```

Yields:

```
sys1    3
sys4    1
sys5    1
sys2    2
Name: col3, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want specifically for col1. if there are more sys1 then the count >3. How can i achieve the sum with reference to col1.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: @GirijaRaniKaretla, add the expected output in your question please